# Is there a way to apply Material-UI's ripple effect to non-Material UI components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-select

I love Material-UI's ripple effect on clicking menu items and buttons, but it's fairly challenging to implement on its own. I'd like to apply the effect to another component, for example the individual options created by the react-select library's Select component.

I tried simply overriding react-select's MenuList and MenuItem with Material-UI's versions, but since I use styled-components it ended up passing react-select's numerous props directly down to the DOM and throwing a lot of errors. For whatever reason, it also was ignoring my onClick function.

I've played around a little with trying to include `<ButtonBase />` or the `<TouchRipple />` directly, but so far without luck. Has anyone found a way to make this work? For context, here is my react-select component:

```
<StyledSelect
      value={selected}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options || testOptions}
      classNamePrefix="react-dropdown"
      className="react-dropdown-container"
      placeholder="Select Item"
      components={{
        DropdownIndicator: DropdownArrowIcon,
        IndicatorSeparator: null
        // this is where I initially tried to override MenuItem and MenuList
      }}
    />
```

Comment: [It looks like this has been done](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-material-ripple). Is that the idea?

Comment: Have you looked through the react-select autocomplete demo: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#react-select?